# Определить, на какую страницу перенаправляют пользователя

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть сайт, который вводится в строку браузера, допустим это `http://microsoft.com/`, далее браузер перескакивает на `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx`.

Как, имея url, определить, на какую страницу перебрасывает пользователя при заходе на опр. страницу?

1. `$url_s;` // отсюда берем url
2. `$url_f;` // сюда охота поместить значение адреса после перенаправления

Answer (score 1):

Можно через JavaScript следить за `location.href` и передавать значение с помощью AJAX PHP скрипту. А напрямую через PHP незьзя это реализовать ИМХО

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   @header('Refresh: 3; URL=http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx');
   echo 'Через 3 сек. вы будете перенаправлены на новую страницу.';
   exit;
?>
```

*я еще вот так делал, однажды была необходимость:*

Запрос на страницу http://test.ru/test_connect.php

```
<?php 
    switch ($_REQUEST['CITY']) {
case 1:
    $url = "http://test.ru/test_1.php";
    break;
default: // Если другое значение
    $url = "http://test.ru/test_2.php";
}
header('Location: ' . $url);
exit;
?>
```